# Ray Tune Stuck with multiple runs

Tags: optimization, parallel-processing, reinforcement-learning, hyperparameters, ray

Hi I am trying hyper parameter optimization with ray tune.
Below is my code implementation.

However I get stuck and can't get the result back even though there aren't any error messages.

```
@ray.remote
def main:
    do_somthing
    return loss

def ray_pick_best_hypter(config):
    runs = 10
    loss_avg = np.mean(ray.get([main.remote(config,run=x) for x in range(runs)]))
    tune.report(loss_avg=loss_avg)
```

```
config = load_config()
analysis = ray.tune.run(ray_pick_best_hypter, config=config,progress_reporter=reporter)
```

The below code works fine, but I want to run multiple experiments and get the mean value.

```
def ray_pick_best_hypter(config):
    loss_avg = ray.get([main.remote(config,run=x))
    tune.report(loss_avg=loss_avg)
```

What is the problem in the code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are starting multiple distributed training processes from within your trainable. Each call to `main.remote()` will start a new distributed task. Since you're starting 10 of them at the same time, they will try to run in parallel.
However, the default resource allocation for each trial is usually just 1 CPU - so the remote tasks cannot be scheduled.

What you can do to resolve this is to pass `resources_per_trial={"cpu": 11}` - that way each of your remote tasks will have their own CPU to run on.

Comment: Unfortunatley, I tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: It gets stuck even when I just set runs=1